# Create a custom navigation bar like camera roll image picker has it

Tags: ios, swift

I have a modally presented view controller which is not in the navigation stack but needs a navigation bar to cancel the selection. The VC is presented by another VC which is a popup (a real one not a fullscreen view). I need a navigation bar in it to present a title and a cancel-button in the upper right hand corner just like the standard camera roll image picker has it.

Here's what I tried so far:

- I added the navigation bar manually by dragging it to the view in the storyboard and attached it with constraints. That works great but the problem is that the navigation bar is too small. It doesn't mind the status bar above it so the cancel button and the title are very close (almost overlapping) to the status bar.
- Tried to increase the navigation bar's height but apple doesn't allow changing the frames of navigation bars.
- Tried push it down a bit with constraints but that results in a white background color for the status bar since the controller has a white background.
- Implemented a new navigation controller just for the one view that needs the bar. But that will give me a standard navigation bar with an arrow in the top left corner which doesn't really fit the navigation feeling since the view is presented modally (from the bottom). Also this seems to be a bit much overhead.

What can I do to achieve a camera-roll-like navigation bar?

BTW: I work with swift.

**EDIT:**
I tried this but setting the height value fails obviously since it's not allowed.

```
@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    navigationBar.frame.height = 44.0
}
```

Comment: You should post code of any attempts you've made towards solving your issue. Without context it's very hard for us to figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Well I added some code now but honestly I don't really know what code I should add that helps you to solve this problem. Most of the things I tried happened in the storyboard plus I don't think that code helps understanding my problem. What I need is the right idea of how to do this and not to find a mistake in my code or something like that...

Comment: I totally understand, it just generally shows you've made a bit more effort or rather makes it obvious that you have to us. You'll normally receive more help too if your question isn't just pure text too. I know it's hard sometimes, but its usually a great idea :)

Comment: Okay I see what you mean and i appreciate you're trying to help me get more attention to my post. I will consider this in future posts but for this one I really can't find anything code-related that would be helpful to post. I think i described what I tried so far in the text...

Comment: Two ideas that come to mind: (1.) build it w/ a custom UIView that contains the nav buttons & elements needed or (2.) fake it by using a custom container view controller technique.

Comment: why dont you hide the actual nav bar in the controller and implement a plain uiview that holds the buttons you need? just make it height 44 and nobody will notice

Comment: Thanks for the workaround ideas but I found a solution to actually solve the problem. But can anybody tell me why I get downvoted here??? I stated correctly and clearly what I tried to do - there just is no more code snippets to post! Do you even notice that it's a very bad thing for new community members to get downvoted? There are tons of other questions here on SO that have way less of "what you tried to do" and still get upvoted. So if there really is a reason please let me know why you downvote or don't do it if there isn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution to this:

1. Set the VC as the delegate for the navigation bar
2. Conform to protocol UIBarPositioningDelegate
3. Implement
   `func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
       return .TopAttached
   }`
4. Push the navigation bar down with constraints by 20p
5. Voila